# MongoDB not saving data because "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm testing NodeJS and MongoDB. So, I've created an html file with a form.

**That form grabs the user input and tries to save it to a Mongo database.**

I've tried manually inserting the values into mongo using the console and it works.

I've started node server writing down `node` at the terminal, inside my EC2 amazon web server. **I've already installed both (node and mongo).**

**The form looks like this:**

```
<form>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
<input type="submit" onclick="avisoPago.insertarDB()" class="btn btn-danger" value="Avisar del pago ahora"></input>
```

**And here's what I'm trying to do in the js file:**

```
"use strict";
const mongojs = require("mongojs");
//string connection
const db = mongojs("localhost:27017/pagosDB",["pagosDB"]);

var avisoPago = {
    email: function () {    return $('#email').val();   },    
    insertarDB: function(){
            db.pagos.insert({
                email:"nadie@example.com",
                //I've also tried email:"this.email()",
                estado: "pendiente"
            });
    }

}
```

**I've also installed mongojs** (using `npm install mongojs`).

But I get this error `avisos-de-pago.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Note: Line 4 of the JS file is: `const mongojs = require("mongojs");`)

I know thata there is something very silly that I'm missing here...

Comment: You're trying to `require` in *browser-side code*? What browser-side library module loading system are you using? (I don't think any are synchronous; only server-side Node has synchronous `require`.) When you say you've "installed" mongojs do you on the *server* or you've actually "installed" it in the client somehow (e.g., with bower, browserify, etc)?

Comment: I've installed inside the Amazon EC2 with 'sudo apt-get install nodejs' (it's an ubuntu server). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Where does your `insertarDB` function run? The browser or the server? (i.e., is it included inside of or by a `<script>` HTML element?) Do you understand the difference between client-side and server-side code? (To be clear, I don't mean to sound rude! The distinction between server and client code is instrumental to this situation, so it is critical to first assess your understanding of the distinction between client/server code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS is a server-side technology, not a client-side technology. In this case, NodeJS calls, like require(), do not work in the browser.

See [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) if you wish to serve browser-specific modules from NodeJS.